# How can we assign typehead for dynamic form fields in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

How can we assign the typehead for dynamic form fields? This is the stackblitzlink [link]"https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oxkiku"

This is my typescript code:

```
      @ViewChild('languageInstance') languageInstance: NgbTypeahead
      focusLanguage$ = new ReplaySubject<string>()
      clickLanguage$ = new ReplaySubject<string>()


      /** Language */
      searchLanguage = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
        let debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(debounceTime(200), distinctUntilChanged())
        let clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.clickLanguage$.pipe(
          filter(() => !this.languageInstance.isPopupOpen())
        )   
        let inputFocus$ = this.focusLanguage$

        return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
          map(term => (term === '' ? this.languages
            : this.languages.filter(
              (lang) => lang.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 7)
          )
        )
      }
```

The above code works for single form field.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a few ways, I will highlight two ways.

1. Use [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) with the static property set to false. This tell the compiler that you template reference is dynamic and then you would have to option of using a *flag* to determine when to set up and subscribe to your observable which is dependent on this element.
2. Another way you could do it is to use [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) which is innately dynamic. It has a changes method which is an observable the emits events when the elements you have tagged with the query name has changed / modified.

I created a stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jfpnyf) for you to check out what i mean between both implementations.